# How to remove everything before a specific string

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I need to get clean output from wireshark but recently i noticed that i've been getting outputs where my cut command doesn't work anymore

Data from wireshark

```
C.'¢¢@)ù¨.fEo³@(@¹³³÷÷P*,§ýý {P¹'GET /2015/dec/alltracks/playlist.m3u8
```

I used to use `cut -f2 -d" "` but now i notice some entries come with multiple spaces so my command fails.

How would I get rid of everything before GET, including the word GET? The goal is to get only `/2015/dec/alltracks/playlist.m3u8`

Comment: This appears to be a TCP/IP header. If someone connects from 10.47.45.54, the word "GET" would appear in the middle of the binary garbage. Surely wireshark has an option to skip the header or otherwise format output, without you trying to parse network protocols as text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the following regular expression

`.*GET`

Where `.*` recognises any characters (the * means zero or more) and `GET` recognises what you want including the leading space, so the output would be what you desire

```
sed "s/.*GET //g"
```

We would replace what we find with nothing (`//`).

s is for substitute while g is for global (which, depending on the case may or may not be necessary, although I'd recommend you to use it if you are willing to modify more than a line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GNU grep` in [PCRE-mode](http://www.pcre.org) enabled by `-P` flag and `-o` flag to print only the matching word.

```
grep -Po ".*GET \K(.*)" input-file 
/2015/dec/alltracks/playlist.m3u8
```

Using a `perl regEx`

```
perl -nle 'print "$1" if /.*GET (.*)/' input-file
/2015/dec/alltracks/playlist.m3u8
```